# Click event on behind is triggered when wrap in a label

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a problem with click event on behind element. I have an input with another element to reset it. This element is positioned absolutely before the input.

The input has a click event that I want block when I clicked in the reset element. **This works fine when both elements aren't in a LABEL tag**:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.popup_selector', function(e){
 alert('Input cliked, if clicked in X it is an error');
});

$('i').click(function(e){
 $('input').val(''); // clear the input
});
```

```css
i {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.5em;
  top: 0.1em;
  width: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

i:after {
  content: 'disable-click';
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input {
  padding-right: 2em;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <i class='clear'>X</i>
  <input type="text" class="popup_selector" />
</div>
```

**The problem occurs when both elements are wrapped by a LABEL tag**. When I click in the reset element, the input click event is triggered and this is a problem:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.popup_selector', function(e){
 alert('Input cliked, if clicked in X it is an error');
});

$('i').click(function(e){
 $('input').val(''); // clear the input
});
```

```css
i {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.5em;
  top: 0.1em;
  width: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

i:after {
  content: 'disable-click';
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input {
  padding-right: 2em;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <div>
    <i class='clear'>X</i>
    <input type="text" class="popup_selector" />
  </div>
</label>
```

Anybody know how to fix it?

Thanks you very much.

Tested in chrome 51.

Comment: I think click on label triggers the click on input, try put the clear outside the label.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this it will work

```
$('i').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('input').val(''); // clear the input
  });
```

Comment: Perfect. I tested it before I wrote the "after" pseudoclass and it didn't work. With after pseudoclass the e.preventDefault works correctly. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

Default behavior of labels if clicked is `focus` on `input` element wrapped in it or associated with it using `for` attribute.

Use `e.preventDefault()` to prevent default behavior

```js
$(document).on('click', '.popup_selector', function(e) {
  alert('Input cliked, if clicked in X it is an error');
});

$('i').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('input').val('');
});
```

```css
i {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.5em;
  top: 0.1em;
  width: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 100
}
i:after {
  content: 'disable-click';
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
}
input {
  padding-right: 2em;
}
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <div>
    <i class='clear'>X</i>
    <input type="text" class="popup_selector" />
  </div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the **[spec](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/label)**,

> In the majority of current web browsers, the text that’s associated with a given form control (by being contained within the  and  tags) also becomes a clickable area. Thus, if the form control is something small, like a checkbox or radio button, *you can massively increase the “hit area” for the mouse user by applying a label to it*.

So the alternative here is to insert a hack on label click,

```
$('label').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.popup_selector', function(e){
 alert('Input cliked, if clicked in X it is an error');
});

$('i').click(function(e){
 $('input').val(''); // clear the input
});
$('label').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
i {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.5em;
  top: 0.1em;
  width: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

i:after {
  content: 'disable-click';
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input {
  padding-right: 2em;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <div>
    <i class='clear'>X</i>
    <input type="text" class="popup_selector" />
  </div>
</label>
```